# How to reference ng-template in component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ng-template

How do I reference `<ng-template #modal_Template>`in my component.ts file. Previously, I called a modal via a button on my html file and used this `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(modal_Template)">Create template modal</button>` but now  I need to call it in my component file after an event is fired. Any idea how to do this? I tried `@ViewChild('modal_Template', {static: false}) modalTemp: ElementRef;` but that doesn't seem to work.

**html:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(modal_Template)">Create template modal</button>


<ng-template #modal_Template>
   //modal code  
</ng-template>
```

**component file**

```
import { Component, TemplateRef, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild('modal_Template', {static: false}) modalTemp: ElementRef;

  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) { }
  //modal
  modalRef: BsModalRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.modalTemp.nativeElement);
  }

  //modal func
  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template,{ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
  }


  //series of events
  someFunctionEvent(){
     //need to call modal function with the referenced #modal_Template variable as an argument
     this.openModal(this.modalTemp.nativeElement.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: show your more ts code.

Comment: ok hold on. Will post the whole thing.

Comment: Or recreate on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Hi @HsuanLee  I added the code. Hope this helps

Comment: I think template reference provide element as a comment. So you can't access value property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to get `nativeElement.value`.

If there is only one `ng-template` in the template, you can use the way provided by @Sam instead of the template reference variable.

```
@ViewChild('modal_Template', {static: false}) modalTemp: TemplateRef<void>;

someFunctionEvent(){
  this.openModal(this.modalTemp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it.

Answer (score 0):

`@ViewChild(TemplateRef, {static: false}) template: TemplateRef<Object>;`

`<ng-template>Content</ng-template>`

Can find more in their docs here - https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description